# SQL Auto-increment ID python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing a program where I am able to add a bread to an Oracle 11g database. The code I've got so far allows me to add the ID manually but it SHOULD auto increment when added so not needing the ID.

```
    BreadID = int(input("Enter the bread ID: "))
    Name = input("Please enter the name for the new bread: ")
    LoafPrice = int(input("Enter the price in pence: "))
    Calories = int(input("Enter the calories: "))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO BREAD VALUES (:BID,:BName,:BCal,:BPrice)",{'BID':BreadID, 'BName':Name, 'BPrice':LoafPrice,  'BCal':Calories,})
    con.commit()
```

This is the code I have for manually adding it. I've searched online for the answer how to add auto increment but all have failed to provide me with errors and more problems.

I have seen online that just leaving the ID column out will allow auto increment but I get this 'ORA-00947: not enough values' even though I've specified the column names.

Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while now.:)

Comment: As you said, it should work with leaving ID column. Are you sure you left it out blank in both places, I mean VALUES() and in {}?

Comment: Yes positive. This is what I have 'cur.execute("INSERT INTO BREAD VALUES (:BName,:BCal,:BPrice)",{'BName':Name, 'BPrice':LoafPrice,  'BCal':Calories,})' and im getting the error 'ORA-00947: not enough values'.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before, try specify the column name in your SQL expression and give BreadID a NULL.

So the sql expression will look something like:

```
INSERT INTO BREAD (BID, BName, BCal, BPrice)
VALUES
(NULL, 'French Toast', 0, 100);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello thank you, I tried this. It looked like this ' cur.execute ("INSERT INTO BREAD (BID, BName, BCal, BPrice) VALUES", {NULL, 'Name', 'LoafPrice', 'Calories'}) ' which I think is right? (sorry if its not, a bit new to this) and I'm getting the error ' name 'NULL' is not defined'. Thanks

Comment: @RexRichards the NULL here should be a string with the sql statement,  not a variable, so it should be like: `"INSERT INTO BREAD (BID, BName, BCal, BPrice) VALUES (NULL, :BName,:BCal,:BPrice)", {'Name', 'Price', 'Calories'}`.

Comment: Ah okay makes a bit more sense now, not as much as this new error.. ' TypeError: expecting a dictionary, sequence or keyword args ' haha thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: @RexRichards Oh sorry, the variable should be a dictionary, `"INSERT INTO BREAD (BID, BName, BCal, BPrice) VALUES (NULL, :BName,:BCal,:BPrice)", {'BID': 'Name', 'BPrice': 'Price', 'BCal': 'Calories'}`, Does that work for you?

Comment: sadly not, I am getting this error 'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number'